# Disable page numbers for title page and toc in combine

Tags: titles, combine, pagestyle

I am preparing a collection of contributions for an upcoming conference. using the combine package. It seems that everything works as planned so far, except that the title page and table of content page are numbered page 1 and page 2. I would like to disable the displaying of the page numbers but the command \pagestyle{empty} does not do the trick. Does anyone have an idea? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Have you tried `\thispagestyle{empty}`? Do you use the `tocloft` package to modify the appearance of the ToC? If so, give `\tocloftpagestyle{empty}` a try.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! With \thispagestyle{empty}, I get no page number on the toc page. However, the title page is still numbered as page 1. The tocloft package does not change anything about it.

Comment: Your write-up is extremely generic, and as a result it's not possible to diagnose the situation with any degree of meaningful accuracy, let alone offer a cure. E.g., which document class do you employ? Please be more informative.

Comment: As I mentioned, it is a combine document. Apparently, the '\maketitle' command somehow forces the display of a page number. The problem disappeared when I designed the title page manually.

Comment: You had mentioned that you use `combine`. However, you didn't mention until just this latest comment that you use `\maketitle`. This piece of information is very important. Whenever you use `\maketitle`, make sure that `\thispagestyle{empty}` comes *after* `\maketitle` if you want `\thispagestyle{empty}` to have an effect.